# Why can I call the .between? method on a Fixnum?

Tags: ruby, comparable, fixnum

For example, if I type the following in irb, it returns Fixnum.

```
20.class
=> Fixnum
```

Also,

```
20.between?(10, 30)
=> true
```

However, when I'm looking at the Ruby documentation, it says that .between? is part of the Comparable Module, which I didn't call yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `Fixnum` includes `Comparable`.

```
Fixnum.ancestors
# => [Fixnum, Integer, Numeric, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Whatever is defined on an ancestor is available unless it is overwritten by a closer ancestor (or itself).

Answer (score 1):

The `Fixnum` includes (mixin) the `Comparable` module:

```
p Fixnum.included_modules

# [Comparable, Kernel]
```